# How to get the Highest price using Xquery

Tags: xml, xquery

How to get the highest price using XQuery ? i'm trying to learn the basics of XML and XQuery , and thanks in advance!

```
    <catalog>
    <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
</catalogue>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The highest price is simply `max(//price)`. If you want the book(s) with the highest price, the simplest way is `//book[price=max(//price)]`, though that's not necessarily the most efficient (depending on your optimizer).